# Close slack entirely, not just the window

Tags: windows-10, slack

I am using slack on windows.

Everytime I close the app, the window closes, but the application is still running - I can see it consuming lots of memory in task manager. I have to "end task" there to close it entirely. This is contrary to most other apps, incl. Chrome.

I want to make sure that the application stops running when I close it and I don't have to "end task" everytime . How can I do this?

Comment: There is likely an option within Slack to control this functionality. You can always end the Slack task using Task Manager.

Comment: I believe that slack "closes" by "Minimizing to the task tray". so to close it, find its icon in the system task tray, and right click it to select "Quit Slack". alternately, you can press Ctrl+Q while a slack window is in focus.

Comment: @FrankThomas ctrl-Q, that's what I was looking for. thanks, if you added an answer with that I can accept it.